# How to reconfigure YOLO2 output layer for a specific volume?

Tags: yolo, deeplearning4j, dl4j

Hi dl4j stackers is it possible to get a yolo variant other than the `5` default params  `[x, y, w, h, p]`  here's what I have from the default *dl4j-examples* repo on github for a `13 x 13` grid-locked image

```
...
graphBuilder.addLayer("convolution2d_23",
                new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(1,1)
                        .nIn(1024)
                        .nOut(nBoxes* (5 +nClasses))//don't want the 5 default params always
                        .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
                        .stride(1,1)
                        .convolutionMode(ConvolutionMode.Same)
                        .weightInit(WeightInit.RELU)
                        .activation(Activation.IDENTITY)
                        .cudnnAlgoMode(cudnnAlgoMode)
                        .build(),
                "activation_22")
                .addLayer("outputs",
                        new Yolo2OutputLayer.Builder()
                                .boundingBoxPriors(priors)
                                .build(),
                        "convolution2d_23")
                .setOutputs("outputs");
graphBuilder.build();
...
```

I need a re-configuration for the `Yolo2OutputLayer` or  a custom  `Yolo2OutputLayer` class for an
output layer capable of outputing any specific volume. currently
I need to output a volume `13 x 13 x 80` in which a unit slice `1 x 1x 80 =  1 x 1 x 2[x, y, w, h, p, c, a0, a1,..., a31]`

> > where 2 equals number of bounding boxes per cell 
> >         `x` - bounding box x coordinate - *1*
> >         `y` - bounding box y coordinate - *1*
> >  
> >         `w` - bounding box width - *1*
> >  
> >         `h` - bounding box height - *1* 
> >         `p` - bounding box object confidence - *1*
> >         `c` -  bounding box class(3 classes) - *3*
> >         `a0...a31` - my custom parameters  - *32*

Comment: thought about using the bounding box class `c` to encode my params `a0, ..., a31` since I can just change the nClasses variable from the code, I actually don't want a softmax multiclass classification, I want the kinda multi label classification as with the default 5 params

Comment: It sounds like we could use multiple outputs to achieve this. Have you tried to do that?

Comment: do you mean connecting additional output layers to "convolution2d_23" i.e. `YoloOutputlayer + AdditionalOutputlayers`

Comment: Yes, that kind of thing, see this network for example: https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/blob/master/rl4j/rl4j-core/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/rl4j/network/ac/ActorCriticFactoryCompGraphStdConv.java

Comment: **@Samuel Audet** aiswear if nobody else in the world it can only be you man... the perfect life saver. Jah bless!!!